# React NavLink href mapping from dictionary not working?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to map my values from a dictionary to NavLink fields. For some reason this exact method works perfectly with react Button's, but not when using it with NavLink.

My dictionary has keys and values that are lists containing 2 values: Name and URL. For example

```
const links = {
    key1: ["key1Name", "key1URL"],
    key2: ["key2Name", "key2URL"]
}
```

and I am using this function to map to my NavLink

```
{Object.values(links).map((key, index) => ( 
    <div className="centered">
        <NavLink className="splashButton" href={key[1]}>{key[0]}</NavLink>
    </div>
))}
```

While this works for my Button mapping, when I try with NavLink, I get this strange error for the href that I don't get with the same exact code for Button

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: NavLinkProps | Readonly<NavLinkProps>): NavLink<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | Element' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: NavLinkProps, context: any): NavLink<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | Element' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2769)

index.d.ts(1933, 9): The expected type comes from property 'href' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NavLink<unknown>> & Readonly<NavLinkProps> & Readonly<...>'
index.d.ts(1933, 9): The expected type comes from property 'href' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<NavLink<unknown>> & Readonly<NavLinkProps> & Readonly<...>'
```

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The NavLink component requires a `to` prop instead of the `href`.

```js
<NavLink ... to={key[1]}>...</NavLink>
```

Reference: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

Comment: My issue using `to` with the reactstrap NavLink is that it disables my link when using it with the map, making it un-clickable. When using `to` with react-router-dom NavLink, it only works with internal links, and all of my links are external. `href` isn't working with either NavLink, Link, or even just the normal `<a>` tag.